# How to call ASP .NET MVC WebAPI 2 method properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have created separated project for **ASP .NET MVC WebAPI 2** and I would like to call `Register` method. (I use a project is created by VS2013 by default.)

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    .... 

    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = model.UserName
        };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

        if (errorResult != null)
        {
            return errorResult;
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

I use a **simple WPF app** to do this. I am not sure about the syntax to call this method and pass username and password to it due`RegisterBindingModel`.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        HttpClient client;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();        
        }

        private  void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Test();
        }

        private async void Test()
        {
            try
            {
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
                handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;

                handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test01","test01"); 

                client = new HttpClient(handler);
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:22678/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); // It  tells the server to send data in JSON format.

                var response = await client.GetAsync("api/Register");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw on error code.

                // How to pass RegisterBindingModel ???     
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<?????>();

            }
            catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException jEx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(jEx.Message);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is depending from routing of yor Web API service but seems to be you have forgotten controller name in route.

By default it should be

```
api/Account/Register
```

Or your code

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:22678/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 
var response = await client.PostAsync("api/Account/Register", ...body content...);
```

And by the way HTTP Verb should be POST and not GET and you should put something into the body.

You can pass through body using [PostAsync method argument called Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In your case the best choice will be use [ObjectContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.objectcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Sample on how to use object you can find here [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client), quote from this article:

> PostAsJsonAsync is an extension method defined in
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions. It is equivalent to the
>   following:

```
var product = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };

// Create the JSON formatter.
MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

// Use the JSON formatter to create the content of the request body.
HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<Product>(product, jsonFormatter);

// Send the request.
var resp = client.PostAsync("api/products", content).Result;
```

Comment: Yes yes... But how I can send  ` RegisterBindingModel`? It has username and password fields... How to put it into the body?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to serialize the model into the post body in a way that the mvc framework can deserialize and form the model again. These posts should help you with the format of the serialized data:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api